# Error with Joda-Time in Android: The datetime zone id 'America/New_York' is not recognised

Tags: android, jodatime

Exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The datetime zone id 'America/New_York' is not recognised

Android code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
DateTimeZone dtZone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York");
DateTime dtus = dt.withZone(dtZone); 

Date dateInUS = dtus.toDate();
System.out.println(dateInUS);
```

Why am I getting this error?

I have loaded the Joda API in Gradle:

```
compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.7.1'
```

Answer (score 22):

I solved the error by adding:

```
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
}
```

Comment: What is `JodaTimeAndroid`?

Comment: https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android JodaTimeAndroid library is a version of Joda-Time built with Android in mind and I wasted 2 hours by not initializing `JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);` in Application class.